# Ubuntu 20.04 and Display settings are not preserved

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdpi, gnome-settings-daemon

I am trying Ubuntu 20.04 and I am impressed with the new fractional scaling feature which works (almost) perfectly.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to save the options when I log out. When I log-in back again all options have been reset, and it is quite annoying.

Any idea what I am missing?

Bug confirmed in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1852860).

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @K7AAY why are you adding "Ubuntu+1" to the titles of all these questions?

Comment: See how guiverc uses Ubuntu+1 in comments above? That's why. It separates questions regarding beta releases of 20.04 from questions regarding 20.04 once it is officially released. Ubuntu+1 tagging ceases once 20.04 is officially released.

Comment: So @muru , since the 24h quarantine is over and 20.04 is officially out, please would you be able to remove the off-topic tag so people can reply to this question?

Comment: Agreed, I have this problem as well.

Comment: The same problem here, even ALT-F2 and **R** resets them

Comment: In my eyes this is still a bug report.

Comment: @guntbert What's the reason of "ask ubuntu" if only perfect things should be asked? So the problem wasn't about "too early" but not to present problems to the world (even in stable LTS versions of Ubuntu)?

Comment: I came here from Google because I have the same problem and now I'm frustrated about StackExchange because once again it's basically a discussion about why this question is irrelevant.

Comment: Voted to reopen since Focal is now released.